# создание своего события

Tags: javascript, события

1. Подскажите пожалуйста, когда я создаю свое событие, то оно затирает уже встроенное?

```js
var event = new Event("click");
var elem = document.getElementById("test");

elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(1);
})

elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```css
#test {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Клац</div>
```

2. Я хочу использовать метод `dispatchEvent` на элементе, но использую встроенное событие `click`. Где взять объект события, что бы искусственно сгенерировать событие?

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("test");

elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(1);
})

//elem.dispatchEvent(event); где взять event?
```

```css
#test {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Клац</div>
```

Comment: _когда я создаю свое событие, то оно затирает уже встроенное?_ - что значит затирает уже встроенное?

Comment: _Я хочу использовать метод dispatchEvent на элементе, но использую встроенное событие click_ - а ты используй dispatchEvent.

Comment: Если присмотришься, то ответ на твой второй вопрос заключен в твоем первом вопросе :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. При вызове `new Event(...)` - создается **объект события**, и ничего не "затирается".
2. Полученный объект можно передать в метод [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent). Таким образом ответом будет являться следующий код

   ```js
   var elem = document.getElementById("test");

   elem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     console.log(1, e);
   })

   var myClickEventObj = new Event("click");
   elem.dispatchEvent(myClickEventObj);
   ```

   ```css
   #test {
     padding: 20px;
     background: #000;
     color: #fff;
     text-align: center;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="test">Клац</div>
   ```

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю как работают встроенные события. Исходя из твоего ответа, я могу предполагать, что когда к `EventTarget` привязывают стандартный обработчик события, то при самом событии автоматически создается новый объект `Event` и его грубо говоря нельзя получить, что бы использовать через `dispatchEvent`. По этому нужно самому создавать его и имитировать вызов вручную, как это сделал ты.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, не понял ничего, что ты написал после первого предложения.

Comment: Как и я не понял твой ответ.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, какой именно из двух пунктов непонятен: что при вызове конструктора создается объект? или чтобы передать объект куда-то его надо создать?

Comment: но мне нужен тот объект, который генерирует стандартный обработчик события, если это вообще возможно.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, обработчик события ничего не генерирует. Почему ты думаешь что тебе он нужен? Единственное отличие от прямого вызова конструктора - это значение поля `isTrusted`,

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84302/discussion-between---and-grundy).

Answer (score 0):

1. Если вызывать `new Event(<имя существующего события>)` то вернет обычный экземпляр события(Event) с типом указанным в первом аргументе(будет доступно через свойство type). Когда вызывается `dispatchEvent` то срабатывают все обработчик событий которые подписаны на этот тип события и которые вы давали через `addEventListener` и в эти обработчики событий попадет созданный вами экземпляр Event.

```js
const event = new Event('myCustomEvent')
const elem = document.getElementById('test')

elem.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', () => {
  console.log('Я всеравно вызвался')
})

const event2 = new Event('myCustomEvent')

elem.dispatchEvent(event2)
```

```html
<div id="test">Клац</div>
```

2. Если нужно получить событие клика и иметь возможность указать для него стандартные свойство, то для клика можно использовать [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) , [вот](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event#Introduction) список всех видов событий.

```js
var e = new MouseEvent("click", {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true,
  clientX: 100,
  clientY: 100
});

console.log( e.clientX ); // 100
```

Свои события можно создать как [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events#%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F) написано через `new CustomEvent(...)`.

Comment: Глянь в консоль [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/Devinora/c2a3h9oq/1/). Как по мне, это опровергает твое умозаключение по поводу того, возвращает уже существующее событие. По поводу того, что создавать событие вручную, то это такое. Может есть ребята, которые лучше понимают как это работает и более точно подскажут можно или нет. Было бы хорошо, если бы с отсылками на спецификацию, ибо очень легко ввести в заблуждение.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный я написал что "вернет уже существующее событие", я тут не совсем правильно ответил как уже понял, правильнее было бы написать: "вернет обычный объект события с типом указанным в первом аргументе", когда вызывается dispatchEvent то срабатывают все обработчики которые подписаны на этот тип события и которые вы давали через `addEventListener` и в обработчики событий попадет созданный вами экземпляр Event. Если смотреть на код вашего примера, то можно увидеть что по сути это тот же код что и у меня в первом коде, просто я не так выразился.